# Action dependant on data from another state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react-redux app with 3 reducers: `clientPrivileges`, `userFilter` and `userData` acting on my store.

A table component is used to present the data for each user and a drop down component is used to filter this table for specific users. When the drop down is selected for a specific user I need to call the backend to retrieve the data. This is the action associated with this:

```
selectUser(userId, dispatch) {
    api.getUserData(userId, accessTypeId, (data) => {
        dispatch(userActions.update(data));
    });

    return{
        type: selectUser,
        userId
    }
}
```

However you can see that I have an argument called `accessTypeId` which needs to be sent to the backend as well as the `userId`. This value has been set in  the store using the `clientPrivileges` reducer on login to the app.

I can't see any other way other than setting `accessTypeId` as a prop for the drop-down component in its `mapStateToProps`. And then in the component itself:

```
this.props.users.map(u => {

    function onClick() 
    {
        selectEndUserGroup(u.id, this.props.accessTypeId);
    } 
    return <div id={"filter_group_"+u.id} key={u.id} onClick={onClick}>{name}</div>
```

But now I've destroyed my generic drop-down component with an `accessTypeId` property. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want your action to have access to a value stored in the Redux state, yes?

Redux-Thunk handles this nicely.  The code would look something like this;

```
selectUser(userId) {
    return function(dispatch, getState){

        var accessTypeId = getState().[PATH TO REDUX STATE ELEMENT]
        api.getUserData(userId, accessTypeId, (data) => {
            dispatch(userActions.update(data));
        });

        dispatch({
            type: selectUser,
            userId
        })
    }
}
```